# How can I load an image, draw on it (the original size) but scale it back to fit a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Currently I have this code:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'assets/img/img.png';
```

This load an image inside my canvas. After that I have a code which draws some graphics on the image.

Currently I have scaled the image file to be with the size of the canvas. But I would like to have it in much higher resolution like it was originally and to be able to draw on the original one. But show the final image scaled inside the canvas window. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Resize or set initial size of canvas to match image dimensions, do the additional drawing, then scale the canvas down?

Comment: If the drawing process is slow this will be noticeable. Is there another way around?

Comment: I got it. I can create a separate canvas element which is not visible. Load the original image there and do the drawing. After that scale it to fit the visible canvas. and use the invisible one when we want to export the file.

Comment: Or you can resize the image on the server before loading so it's smaller when you manipulate the canvas.

Comment: I don't want to put load on the server. But still I need the edited bigger image when the user wants to export it. Anyway - thanks for the help : )